# Can't find String.Replace in Razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

See it is not there! Why? 
I am assigning the primary key of the results that are getting returned as the id, some of them start with "#" and it gets it confused with hyperlink bookmarks in HTML so wanted to replace that "#" with something but can't find the method in here .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Replace` is an instance function. It would have to be something like `"some string".Replace(...)`. You're looking at the static functions that exist on the `String` class.